# How to tune Kafka Connect for pulling data from a large SQL Server database using kafka-connect-jdbc?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to pull data from a SQL Server database which holds data close to 5 TB. I will be using `kafka-connect-jdbc` developed by confluent.

How to go about tuning Kafka Connect to pull large data? I see many `Socket connection closed` errors. 
Will it need high configuration Kafka Connect nodes.
What are the parameters that need to be tuned for such use case?

Is there a better way for migrating such huge amount of data from one database to another, let us say into a Distributed database?

Comment: It might make more sense to use a CDC / snapshot based approach rather than opening a large number of JDBC connections

Comment: Can you elaborate on snapshot based approach? I haven't heard about it. Does that work between different database technologies?

Comment: Database snapshots are just like point in time backups.  Rather than read the database, you're reading a file of database rows into Kafka.. I watched a presentation on Debezium, and it was mentioned to use that for large databases, then flip it over to the polling/CDC methods once you have all the records